# Can you go blind if you look at the sunrise and sunset?

Tags: star, the-sun, light, time

Everyine knows its dangerous to look directly at the sun, but can you look safely at sunrises and sunsets without going blind? Because the uv radiaton and the light is much weaker. Or is it still very dangerous? How longcould you look at the sunrise or sunset without damaging your eyes? Will you be ok if you look at the sunrise, or sunset for a few seconds? Or is sungazing unsafe, no matter the time?